# Stationary distribution of random walk on a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk

If you do a random walk on an undirected, connected graph, is the stationary distribution for the probability that you have just traversed edge $e$ uniform over all edges no matter what the graph looks like?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried calculating this for several graphs? Have you tried proving it?

Comment: on the non bipartite case is simple.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think it is true. I wrote some code to do some random walks and it seemed to hold but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @Exodd That's interesting. How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding something to @gmath answer:

if we want to find the probability that you have just traversed an edge $p_{ij}$, knowing that the distribution on the vertex is stationary ($\pi$), we have

$$
p_{ij}=\frac{\pi_i}{d_i}+\frac{\pi_j}{d_j}=\frac{1}{e}
$$

So the distribution on the edge is uniform.

Returning to the original problem, we reach the stationary distribution only if the graph is non bipartite (acyclic in directed graph).

In the bipartite case, we have also a similar stationary distribution, but only by performing two step on the random walk at a time.

An invariant of the distribution of probability in a bipartite graph is in fact the probability to be on a vertex on the left (or right) side of the graph on an even (or odd) step of the random walk.

The two asymptotic distribution that alternate are built like the one above: 
if $P_R$ is the sum of probability on the right side, and $e$ the number of edges, then every node on the right has a probability of
$$
\pi(x)=\mbox{deg}(x)*P_R/e
$$
and similar to the left. The other asymptotic distribution has $P_R$ and $P_L$ switched.

In both cases, the probability distribution on the edges is $1/e$, so it holds everywhere.

Answer (score 9):

The stationary measure of a vertex is proportional to its degree. Let $G$ be a graph with $e$ edges. Then for any vertex the stationary probability measure is $$\pi(x) = \deg(x)/2e.$$ To see it is stationary, note $p(x,y) = 1/\deg(x)$ if $x$ is incident to $y$. Hence $$ \sum_{x} \pi(x) p(x,y) = \sum_{x\sim y} \deg(x)\frac{1}{2e\deg(x)} = \deg(y)/2e  = \pi(y).$$

Comment: Thanks but does this tell me about the measure for the edges?  Sorry if I am missing something simple/obvious.

Comment: Thank you for this but does this give you the stationary distribution for edges or just vertices?

Comment: If your Markov chain is on the vertices, then this gives the stationary distribution. If it is on the edges, then the uniform distribution works (each of them has mass 1/e).

Comment: just a problem: you have a covergence to the stationary distribution only for non bipartite graph.
How do you generalize?

Comment: Yes you are right the convergence does not hold for the Markov chain on bipartite graphs because the chain is periodic. nevertheless the stationary distribution still exists and is what I mentioned. There is a way to make the chain in bipartite maps converge also: make it lazy. In other words, in every step just stay put with prob 1/2 or otherwise move. This will give you the required convergence as it removes periodicity.