# Prove that uniform distribution on a set of vertices $V$ is stationary if the graph is regular.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk, uniform-distribution

I was going through [Random walks on graphs: A survey](http://www.cs.yale.edu/publications/techreports/tr1029.pdf)

It was stated that:

> Uniform distribution on a set of vertices $V$ is stationary if the
>   graph is regular.

Can anyone give me some hints to prove it ?

Comment: gmath's answer here is what you want: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942864/stationary-distribution-of-random-walk-on-a-graph/943100#943100