# Frog on a 3 by 3 matrix

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine a frog (f) on a 3 by 3 matrix, with the frog being able to jump to neighboring places from where it sits. So for example if the frog is at $s_{0,1}$, it can subsequently jump to $s_{0,0}, s_{0,2},s_{1,0},s_{1,1}$ and $s_{1,2}$.

$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
s_{0,0} & f & s_{0,2} \\
s_{1,0} & s_{1,1} & s_{1,2} \\
s_{2,0} & s_{2,1} & s_{2,2} \end{array} \right)$$

Overall there are $9$ configurations for the frog, what is the probability that the frog sits at $s_{0,1}$ after many random jumps? I thought of assigning weights to places on the matrix, by the fact that e.g. $s_{0,1}$ can be reached by $5$ other places, compared to $s_{1,1}$ that has $8$ ways to it. But I don't know how to include this information into the probability calculation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain <- this wiki may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frog jump process is a random walk on this graph.

[image]

It is easy to show that the long run probability
at each node is proportional to its degree, i.e., the number of edges
 adjacent to that node. See gmath's [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942864/stationary-distribution-of-random-walk-on-a-graph).

The degree of the nine nodes are either 8, 5, or 3 and simple
calculations show that the long run probability is 1/5 at the center,
3/40 at each of the four corners, and 1/8 at the other four edge nodes.

Comment: @user929304 If the two frogs move independently, then $p^*=(1/8)(1/8)$ and the formula $1/8+1/8-p^*$ is correct.

Comment: Dear Byron, if i want to learn more about markov chains, given that i know the bare basics of a single chain, is there any starting piece of literature that comes recommended for learning about multiple chains? (And how to estimate their properties)

Answer (score 2):

let $p_{i,j}$ be the probability of frog being on $s_{i,j}$ after "many" jumps. One more jump added is still going to be "many" so you can use the law of total probability :

e.g.: $p_{0,0} = p_{0,1}/ 3 + p_{1,0} / 3$ (the only way for the frog to get to s00 is if it was on s10 or s01, if the frog was on s10 there would be a probability of 1/3 that it will jump onto s00 since s00 is one of three neighbours of s10, similarly with s01)

<strike>You do this with each box giving you 9 simultaneous equations with 9 unknowns, which you can do</strike>

edit: you also need the fact that they all add up to 1

Comment: You're allowed to jump diagonally, though. So it's $p_{0,0} = p_{0,1}/5 + p_{1,1}/8 + p_{1,0}/5$.

Comment: nah, the probability of there being at least one frog on $s_{0,1}$ is $1-(1-p_{0,1})^2$ (1-prob of there being no frog)